# Progress/seek bar for Pharo morphic

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

I'm searching for a visual component such as video progress bar / seek bar or something like this:

[image: Seek bar]
are there something like it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Benjamin van Ryseghem

```
| slider |

slider := SliderModel new.
slider 
    min: 0;
    max: 100;
    whenValueChangedDo: [:value | slider label: value asString ].
slider openWithSpec
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `PluggableSliderMorph` for this purpose:

[image: PluggableSliderMorph]